# Cannot access settings

Tags: gnome

Settings icon shows in bar on left but no action when clicked. However right click opens "All windows" and shows settings window and a red cross. But cannot open settings from here either. Have tried reinstalling Gnome but no change. Also occasionally a figure 2 appears in upper  left screen ?

Please help as very new to Gnome and Ubuntu (20.04) and wish to make this my main system

Comment: Had the same issue on one of my machines after an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 I reinstalled fresh no more problem. May not be your answer but something to think about.

Comment: In bar on left? For me, there is the button "Activities" there. Please check and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling `gnome-control-center`?

`sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center`

GNOME Control Center is the package that has the settings interface.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center

---

I ran into that problem myself on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, I'm not sure how it occured, but this is how I resolved the issue.